# In Rails Devise gem how to modify the send_reset_password_instructions method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to modify the `send_reset_password_instructions` method so that I can send some extra parameters through it to the url. Then I can read that parameter in the url and if its present I will style the view (and the mailer) in a different way.

What I really need to do is send the reset password instead of confirmation email. I have already made my app send the reset password instead of confirmation but now I need to edit the mailer and the view to be different. How can I do this?

Comment: You're asking for two things... which do you want? :) If you want both - maybe two questions (one for each) would work better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK so your question has 2 parts.

- Overriding the `send_reset_password_instructions` method:

  1. Visit the [Devise Github page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/) and find where the method is defined.
  2. Create a file with the same name and relative path in you own app folder. Eg.: Devise has this helper `app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb`, if you want to override it you create the same in you own `app` directory.
  3. Copy the method and override as needed. Devise will automatically pickup the files.
- Editing the views / mailers: You just need to run this command:

  `rails generate devise:views`

You will have the mailer views in you views folder.

Hope this helps :)